# Format float with padding and justification

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting

I know I can do

```
> print '|{:16.3f}|\n|{:16.3f}|'.format(1, 10)
|           1.000|
|          10.000|
```

to pad a number so that the output is a certain number of columns, and I can do

```
> print '|{:<16.3f}|\n|{:<16.3f}|'.format(1, 10)
|1.000           |
|10.000          |
```

to left justify the formatted field.  Is there a way to do both at the same time?  I'd like left justification on a padded number, so my output would look like

```
> print '|{:<format>}|\n|{:<format>}|'.format(1, 10)
| 1.000          |
|10.000          |
```

where `<format>` is what I'm trying to solve for.  Specifically, I want a 6 character formatted floating point number with 3 decimal places left justified to 16 columns.  I know I could solve this with multiple string formats, but I'd like to do it all at the same time.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to know how many blanks to pad on the right until you've processed *all* the input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *have* to embed the formatted number into a wider column:

```
>>> print '|{:16s}|\n|{:16s}|'.format(format(1, '6.3f'), format(10, '6.3f'))
| 1.000          |
|10.000          |
```

I used `format()` function calls to format just the numbers.

Although the `str.format()` parser can handle filling in parameters from formatting slots, you cannot format the formatting output.

Of course, you could just add spaces to your formatting string, since you already control the width of the formatting you *know* there will be 10 spaces after the numbers:

```
>>> print '|{:6.3f}          |\n|{:6.3f}          |'.format(1, 10)
| 1.000          |
|10.000          |
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I want to avoid doing multiple formats.  This may be the only route I have, but currently this doesn't answer my question.  If you can provide references that show that this is the only way to solve this problem then I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @bheklilr how do you provide a reference that something *doesn't* exist? I think this answer is as close as you will get.

Comment: @bheklilr: although you can use formatting for providing *parameters*, you cannot format *formatting output*.

Comment: @MarkRansom You can provide a reference to a specification that lists what is possible, or to something that shows why something is not possible.  It would be easy to find documentation that `'{:f'` is not a valid format specifier, but I couldn't find anything to say why `{:<16 6.3f}'` or something similar isn't allowed.

Comment: @bheklilr: if it is not in the documentation, then it is not allowed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The suggestion of adding literal spaces in the format string seems like the best solution, but I certainly don't like it.  Instead of being able to embed the format in a format specifier it appears I have to more manually encode the width of that field.

Comment: @MarkRansom I did look up the documentation myself, and I didn't see anything that explicitly prohibited what I wanted to do. Since documentation is notorious for being incomplete, I tried several things before posting but could not come to the solution I wanted. I simply wanted to know if it was possible to both justify and pad a numeric field using a single formatting specification. If the answer is no, then it should be a simple matter for someone with as much experience as you seem to possess to clarify or supplement existing documentation with an explanation as to why this is the case.

Comment: @bheklilr: the Python documentation is *not* notorious from being incomplete. Far from it, in fact.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I disagree.  [For example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects), the `threading.Event` object is not an object, it's a factory function, but this is directly contradicted by the documentation which states that `threading.Event` is a class.  The docstring for `Event` states that it's a factory function, and the docstring for `_Event` (the actual type) also states that it's a factory function.  In my opinion, this is not good documentation.

Comment: @bheklilr: if you have specific issues, the project is open source software with a public bug tracker. Feel free to suggest changes; I do so all the time. The threading module is rather old, the documentation may have some warts there, but I can assure you that the string formatting documentation is complete.

Comment: @bheklilr: and I see that the documentation states that `threading.Event` is a factory function, which is true, but nowhere does the documentation state it is a class. It talks about event (lowercase) objects; the factory function returns event objects. Using the term factory function means you cannot use that function for `isinstance` tests. I'm not sure why you have such a beef with that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters [See the full docs on what is supposed to be the `Event` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects).  It clearly states `class threading.Event`, and it also means that you can't inherit from it.  And it's not so much that I have a huge problem with the python documentation, I just don't think it should be touted as the best documentation ever.  Some modules are very well documented, and some aren't, so that means that I have to be cautious with all of them.

Comment: @bheklilr: ah, I see what you mean. I also see that http://bugs.python.org/issue17876 has been filed.

Comment: @bheklilr: and all documentation is a human endeavour, so mistakes will be made. In my experience the Python documentation is some of the best there is, and the project is always open for improvements.